# map mile distance price calculation javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary, distance, point, price

```
var miles = 120;

if (miles > 0 && miles < 10)
{
    miles = miles*50;
}

if (miles > 10 && miles < 40)
{
    miles = ((miles-10)*1.5)+(10*50);
}

if (miles > 40 && miles < 100)
{
    miles = ((miles-40)*2)+(10*1.5)+(10*50);
}

if (miles > 100 && miles < 1000)
{
    miles = ((miles-100)*2.5)+(40*2)+(10*1.5)+(10*50);
}

console.log(miles);
```

please help i'm stuck in between logic

> first 10    //50
>
> total 50    //10*50+ 1.5 (40 miles + 10)

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: fare calculation of two geo point.

Comment: You probably want to put the price in another variable. Reusing a variable for a different purpose is a bad idea.

Comment: What happens when miles equals 40? You need to use if/else if

Comment: something like..
total 100 miles
first 10 miles 50$ per mile
next 40 miles will be 20$ ... meaning 10*50 40*20 total 50miles
next upto 100 miles will be 10$ ......meaning 10*50  40*20  50*10 thats

total.

Comment: You probably need to read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357322/8173752) before asking a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add `else` to your if statements or it won't work

```
var miles = 120;

if( miles > 0 && miles <= 10)
{
    miles = miles*50;
}
else if(miles > 10 && miles <= 40)
{
    miles = ((miles-10)*1.5)+(10*50);
}
else if( miles > 40 && miles <= 100)
{
    miles = ((miles-40)*2)+(10*1.5)+(10*50);
}
else if(miles > 100 && miles <= 1000)
{
    miles = ((miles-100)*2.5)+(40*2)+(10*1.5)+(10*50);
}
else{
    //maybe do something here
}
```

also, you should use another variable for your result.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I noticed is you should be using `if`/`else if` since you really only want to catch into one bucket that structure makes it somewhat more clearly related in a visual sense.

Second you are excluding some numbers by doing `< >` with out either a `<=` or `>=`, for my example I chose to do  `min < variable <= max` but you could just as easily the min variable.

For clarity I separated this out into functions and applied one to the number prototype for ease of use.

```
// check if given number is greater than min less than or equal to max
Number.prototype.between = function(min, max) {
  return (this > min && this <= max);
}

// calculates your mileage amounts
const calcRate = distance => {
  if (distance.between(0, 10)) {
    return ( distance * 50 );
  } else if (distance.between(10, 40)) {
    return ( ( ( distance - 10 ) * 1.5 ) + ( 10 * 50 ) );
  } else if (distance.between(40, 100)) {
    return ( ( ( distance - 40 ) * 2 ) + ( 10 * 1.5 ) + ( 10 * 50 ) );
  } else if (distance.between(100, 1000)) {
    return ( ( ( distance - 100 ) * 2.5 ) + ( 40 * 2 ) + ( 10 * 1.5 ) + ( 10 * 50 ) );
  } else if (distance > 1000) {
    // do something
  }
}
// test variable
let miles = 120;
// test result
let result = calcRate(miles);
// log result
console.log(result);
```